# onchange method of <select> is triggered before model binding

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a list of entities with multiple attributes and I use input fields / selects to be able to update the values from that list view. Here's the relevant part of the list:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.PDILogisticsList)
            {
   <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CommissionNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input
                id="PlannedDeliveryInput"
                type="datetime-local"
                asp-for="@item.PlannedDelivery"
                onchange="UpdateValues('@item.CommissionNumber', '@item.PlannedDelivery', '@item.CarCurrentlyInService', '@item.CarCurrentlyInBodywork', '@item.DouaneRequired')"
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select
                id="CarCurrentlyInServiceSelect"
                asp-for="@item.CarCurrentlyInService"
                onchange="UpdateValues('@item.CommissionNumber', '@item.PlannedDelivery', '@item.CarCurrentlyInService', '@item.CarCurrentlyInBodywork', '@item.DouaneRequired')"
            >
                <option value="True">Yes</option>
                <option value="False">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select
                id="CarCurrentlyInBodyworkSelect"
                asp-for="@item.CarCurrentlyInBodywork"
                onchange="UpdateValues('@item.CommissionNumber', '@item.PlannedDelivery', '@item.CarCurrentlyInService', '@item.CarCurrentlyInBodywork', '@item.DouaneRequired')"
            >
                <option value="">Please choose...</option>
                <option value="True">Yes</option>
                <option value="False">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

The JS section:

```
<script>      
    function UpdateValues(commissionNumber, plannedDelivery, carCurrentlyInService, carCurrentlyInBodywork, douaneRequired)
    {           
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl + '/de/UpdateValues',
            data: {
                commissionNumber,
                plannedDelivery,
                carCurrentlyInService,
                carCurrentlyInBodywork,
                douaneRequired
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {                
              ...
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

When one of the selects or the date field is changed, I send all the information for that entity to the controller and write it to the database.

I have two problems:

1. Some of the douaneRequired fields are empty (''), but in the `select` "Yes" is selected for these entities, although I have one option with an empty value.
2. I pass the values of the parameters in the `onchange="UpdateValues(...)"` method to the JS part. It seems that this call is fired before the value change takes place with the attribute that is connected with `asp-for` because it's always the value prior the change that is being sent.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I tried to pass the values using a direct jquery selector `onchange="UpdateValues('@item.commissionNumber', $('#CarCurrentlyInServiceSelect').val()` but that gives me of course only the values of the very first entity of the list.

Comment: at the time of rendering the HTML, the model values are of course passed to your JS function just **once** and never change. You need to bind handler for the `change` event programmatically in your JS code after the DOM has been loaded.

Comment: instead of passing this `@item.CommissionNumber` right at the rendering time, you need to use the id `PlannedDeliveryInput` to refer to that input value. In the `change` event handler, you get the value from that input ***via its id***. That's how it works. The Razor binding has nothing magical, it just generates the HTML ***once***. For the case of posting FORM, it just generates the input elements with ***correct name***. So it makes some sense of `binding` here (show values when loaded and receive back values when post)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Hopeless, the render time vs. run time info did indeed help me.

To make it easy for me, I have done the following:

1. Added a unique key to every attribute that I wand to write back later:
2. Retrieved the values of the four attributes by their unique key.

   ```
    <td>
          <input id="PlannedDeliveryInput_@item.CommissionNumber" type="datetime-local" asp- 
          for="@item.PlannedDelivery" onchange="UpdateValues('@item.CommissionNumber')"/>
    </td>

    <td>
           <select id="CarCurrentlyInServiceSelect_@item.CommissionNumber" 
    </td>





        function UpdateValues(commissionNumber)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + '/de/SAM/UpdatePDILogisticsUsedCar',
                data: {
                    commissionNumber,
                    plannedDelivery: $('#PlannedDeliveryInput_' + commissionNumber).val(),
                    carCurrentlyInService: $('#CarCurrentlyInServiceSelect_' + commissionNumber).val(),
                    carCurrentlyInBodywork: $('#CarCurrentlyInBodyworkSelect_' + commissionNumber).val(),
                    douaneRequired: $('#PlannedDeliveryInput_' + commissionNumber).val(),
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == "1")
                        $.growl({ title: "Änderung gespeichert", message: "Die Änderung wurde erfolgreich gespeichert!" });
                    else
                        $.growl.error({ message: "Änderung konnte nicht gespeichert werden!" });
                },
            });
        }
   ```

Comment: do you mean you have already solved the problem, right?